# Is there a way to pass information between pages in Reactjs using navlink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using a Django REST framework, storing data in a model.

I am then using Reactjs to consume the API and make GET/POST requests.

Inside the React frontend, I am using react-router-dom to navigate between pages.

I want to be able to click on a specific link, but then also pass on information to the component towards which the link is routed.

This is my index.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my App.js code

```
import './App.css';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Navigation from './Components/ToolBar'
import Main from './Components/Main'

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth='lg' className="App">
        <Navigation/>
        <Main/>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is my Main.js code

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Projects from './Projects';
import Tickets from './Tickets';

const Main = () => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/projects' component={Projects}></Route>
      <Route exact path='/tickets' component={Tickets}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );

  export default Main;
```

This is my Toolbar.js code, which is used for navigating to different pages

```
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigation = () => {

    return (
        <AppBar color='primary'>
            <Toolbar>
                <Button><NavLink to='/projects'>Projects</NavLink></Button>
                <Button><NavLink to='/tickets'>All Tickets</NavLink></Button>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}


export default Navigation
```

And this is my Projects.js code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function Projects() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/projects/')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  if (data) {
    const projects = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.project_code))];

    return (

        <div>
          <h3>These are the current projects</h3>
            {projects.map(item => (
              <p>{item}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
}

export default Projects;
```

Basically what I want to achieve is the following, in my Project.js code, the line item `<p>{item}</p>`, I want to change to a clickable link. When this link is clicked, it needs to take my to a new page, where all the tickets are shown, only related to that specific project, and it needs to use the project_code variable (for that specific project) to send a request to the API. After the API receives that project code, it will send back only the tickets for that specific project.

My problem is passing that project_code from the Projects "page" to a new page, where I can use that project_code to send it to the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, I think nested routes would be the best option. Check out [this example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) to see how you could add it to your logic.

By doing so, you'll end up with routes looking like this:

```
   /project/:projectId // for your project main route
   /project/:projectId/:ticketId // to access a particular ticket
```

This will also allow you to display some kind of Menu, where you can see all your projects/tickets, and freely navigate through them all.